# How to configure a foreign key that is defined in the model with one to zero or one relationship

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-4.3

I have some questions with relationship of ef code first.
My code:

```
public class user
{
    public user()
    {
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class dep
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual user User { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<dep>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.User)
            .WithOptionalDependent();
```

The table dep that code first auto generated has a foreign key named User_Id,
but that is not what I want.
I want to use the column UserId that I defined in the model.
How will I change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can just add an attribute

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
```

on your User property.

Now, the question is why ? You're not in a Database, but in a ORM, an object world. You should work with User Navigation property, not with UserId. And if you need UserId, you should use User.Id.

But... that's your soultion ;)

Comment: when I added the foreignkey attribute,I got this exception:

    One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'dep_User_Source' in relationship 'dep_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following? I didn't test it, but think it should work:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dep Dep { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dep
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class DepConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Dep>
    {
        public DepConfig()
        {
            this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
                    .WithOptional(t => t.Dep);
        }
    }
```

This assumes that Dep must have a User, but a User isn't required to have Dep. I added the property Dep to the User class so you can navigate in both directions.

Hope it helps.